# How to programmatically select between bluetooth and handset for media audio

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to have a set of buttons that operate like the media output chooser in the JB dialer, that will select "headset" "speaker" and "phone handset". I can turn on and off the speaker fine, however switching between having the media output go between the standard handset and the bluetooth headset eludes me.

How can I build and option like the one in the dialer, that controls media output? I have looked at documentation for bluetooth and Audio controls and nothing seems to be working quite right (such as the setScoBluetooth etc.)

Comment: What kind of bluetooth accessory is it? One intended only as a handsfree, or does it also support A2DP?

Comment: The device I am testing it with is A2DP, preferably a solution that does not depend on SCO/A2DP, but at this point I will take what I can get

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of routing policies is platform-specific and therefore might differ slightly between different products, but this is what I'd suggest:

If an A2DP-capable device is paired/connected "for media" use, it should be the default output device for `MUSIC` streams. So if you do nothing, the audio should be routed to the A2DP device.

To route the audio to the loudspeaker instead of the A2DP device, use the AudioManager's `setBluetoothA2dpOn` method with the argument `false`. This method has been marked as deprecated for a long time, but still exists and performs the advertized action last time I checked.

To route the audio to the earpiece, use the `VOICE_CALL` stream type, and use the AudioManager's `setMode` method to change the mode to `MODE_IN_CALL`. You might also want to disable bluetooth with `setBluetoothScoOn(false)`.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I did all ov the above, but still doesnt work